# How can make every line contain 80 characters when to insert lorem ipsum string?

Tags: vimscript-python, textwidth

`set textwidth=80` in my `.vimrc`.

I have written a function to create a lorem ipsum:

```
function! Lorem(num)
python3 << EOF
import random
num = int(vim.eval("a:num"))
words = ['exercitationem', 'perferendis', 'perspiciatis', 'laborum', 
         'eveniet','sunt', 'iure','maxime', 'corrupti']
fixed_length = len(words)
if num > fixed_length:
    a, b = divmod(num, 10)
    words = words * a + words[0:b]
else:
    words = words[0:num]
random.shuffle(words)
result = " ".join(words)
line_nb, col_nb = vim.current.window.cursor
line = vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1]
vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1] = line[:col_nb + 1] + result + line[col_nb + 1:]
EOF
endfunction
```

Now I edit a file:

```
line1
line2
```

The cursor located at the `1` in the first line, `call Lorem(20)` can create the following content:

```
line1maxime iure exercitationem eveniet corrupti laborum perspiciatis perferendis corrupti perferendis sunt maxime perspiciatis exercitationem sunt laborum iure eveniet
line2
```

How can make every line contain 80 characters? Should I add something in Lorem function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add at the end of your function:

```
vim.command("normal! gqq")
```

Such as:

```
function! Lorem(num)
python3 << EOF
import random
num = int(vim.eval("a:num"))
words = ['exercitationem', 'perferendis', 'perspiciatis', 'laborum', 
         'eveniet','sunt', 'iure','maxime', 'corrupti']
fixed_length = len(words)
if num > fixed_length:
    a, b = divmod(num, 10)
    words = words * a + words[0:b]
else:
    words = words[0:num]
random.shuffle(words)
result = " ".join(words)
print(result)
line_nb, col_nb = vim.current.window.cursor
line = vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1]
vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1] = line[:col_nb + 1] + " " + result + line[col_nb + 1:] + "\n"
vim.command("normal! gqq")
EOF
endfunction
```

Comment: Make the format better.

Comment: vim.current.buffer[line_nb - 1] = line[:col_nb + 1] + " " + result + line[col_nb + 1:] + "\n"